# How to set image width and height 100% with CSS?

Tags: html, css

My code:

```
background:url(images/menu_edu.jpg) no-repeat;
```

But only half of the image is getting displayed.

Comment: maybe you should display some more code...it's difficult to tell why this is happening just from one line :)

Answer (score 4):

The element which has the background needs to be the size of the image.

i.e. flower.jpg = 255px x 55px

```
<div class="flower">
    Some text
</div>

.flower {
    background: url(flower.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 255px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

The size of the element cannot be set to the dimensions of the image if you're using a background. You could use javascript to calculate the dimensions though.

Or if you need to repeat the image, you can use repeat, repeat-x or repeat-y on the background tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing enough code, but if the background image is in the `body` element,  it is probably not stretching across the whole viewport.

Try

```
html, body { min-height: 100% }
```

Comment: What does the view port have to do with showing only half of the image?

Comment: @starx try giving a `body` a `background-image` and not expanding it to `100%` height and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display an image, the IMG-tag is much more useful and effective... (and it could be set to width(/&)height = 100%).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your image in full size, no need to use CSS for this

Dont give height and width attribute to the `<img>` tag like
`<img src="this.jpg" />` it will display in full size

But if you want your `<div>` to show its background in full size, then is no other option than assigning the exact image dimensions